# Multiple image retrieving

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a PHP file which retrieves images of users you are following from mysqli database. The problem is that when the images are displayed it displays all images of each users (that is, it displays all images of the first user before displaying all the images of the second user). I want my php file to display all images according to the time posted not displaying all images of one user first. I also added time stamp but it's not still working.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$post = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM userfollow WHERE username = '{$_COOKIE['user']}' ORDER BY stamp DESC");

while($pt = mysqli_fetch_array($post)){

$sfup = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM post WHERE username = '{$pt['currentuser']}' ORDER BY stamp DESC");
while($sup = mysqli_fetch_array($sfup)){

        if($sup['type'] == 'video/mp4'){
        ?>
        <video style="width:100%; height:400px;" src="post/<?php echo $sup['file']?>" controls preload="none"></video>
        <?php
    }else{
        if($sup['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
    ?>
    <img src="post/<?php echo $sup['file'];?>" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #eeeeee"><b><?php echo $pt['currentuser'];?></b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things here

1. No need to Select * if you're not using every column, just select what you need to improve mysql fetch performance.
2. Please use prepared statements. Taking a Cookie and putting it straight into sql query is a security hole a mile wide.
3. You'll probably need to join your 2 tables and order by time posted. The way you have it written it goes through user by user so it doesn't really even matter what order by you put on the second query.